# In tailwind , card layout is half of main width in mobile. pc is fine

Tags: tailwind-css

I am almost crazy..
I don't know why this code width layout is half only in my local machine.

I put this code

```
<div class="flex justify-center">
  <div class="rounded-lg shadow-lg bg-white max-w-sm">
    <a href="#!" data-mdb-ripple="true" data-mdb-ripple-color="light">
      <img class="rounded-t-lg" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/standard/nature/182.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <div class="p-6">
      <h5 class="text-gray-900 text-xl font-medium mb-2">Card title</h5>
      <p class="text-gray-700 text-base mb-4">
        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
        content.
      </p>
      <button type="button" class=" inline-block px-6 py-2.5 bg-blue-600 text-white font-medium text-xs leading-tight uppercase rounded shadow-md hover:bg-blue-700 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-blue-700 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-blue-800 active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in App.vue `<template></template>`

It looks ok with in pc mode

[image]
but in mobile mode, it looks different that I expected.
I don't have any idea. please help me.

I guess `<div id=app></div>` and `<div class="flex ..">` width should not be 900px.
It has to be like 375px.
I am not sure why it happens..
Please give me some solutions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I missed viewport that's why it happens.

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Put this code in your head section, to fix the problem.